# WebBrowser height in codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to show a youtube video within my application.
Currently it works in the emulator but the problem is the video isn't scaled well.
The BorderLayout works fine for the width but i want to give the video a max height as well.

my code:

```
    Container c2 = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    c2.setPreferedH(400);
    WebBrowser player = new WebBrowser();
    player.setURL("https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+temp.getUrl()+"?rel=0");
    c2.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, player);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't invoke `setPreferredH` its generally a mistake.

What did you add c2 into?

I suggest that instead of creating c2 you would set the border layout to the form and add the player component into the center of the form.

Comment: Well the problem is c2 will be generated when u press a button and then added to the center of the higher lying container. Since there is so much other data on the page i cant add it straight to the form. I could generate a new page to show the vid if thats really the only real solution but that would kind of ruin the flow of the app.

Comment: Its a problem to add a web browser into a scrollable parent component. I'm not sure a standalone form would work for you either but I'm pretty sure you will run into issues with your current approach since you are embedding a "sizeless" browser component into a complex layout. Its size will only be determined after the HTML is loaded.

Comment: Hmm i see. Is there an other way to show a youtube video then by using the webbrowser? I'll allready start by putting it in a new form and see what that gives.

Comment: Google disallows any other way so no. You can use media API's for regular video but youtube doesn't expose the actual video stream officially.

Comment: Ok so it does work when i place the webbrowser in a new form.
Problem now is that on my device (Samsung S4) it gives sound but no video..

Comment: You need to make sure you placed the component in the center of a border layout placed on the form.